# How to share a link and a finished text using Share

Tags: flutter, dart, hyperlink, share

I use the [Share](https://pub.dev/packages/share)  package  so that when I click on the icon I can share the link. I would also like that when I share my link, I have a ready-made text description of this link. I tried to do this through Subject, but the result is the link itself without text.

```
 onTap: () {
  Share.share('https://www.youtube.com', subject:  'Nice Service');
 },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
await Share.share(
        'https://www.youtube.com' + ',' + 'Nice Service',
      );
```

Update: use new [share_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus) package like this:

```
Share.share('https://www.youtube.com', subject: 'Nice Service');
```

Comment: But link not working  . It returns 'https://www.youtube.com,Nice Service'